# How to shift between two fragments activities each other in android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have two fragment activities . Now I want to shift between this .Also I want to do this after end of the first fragment activity.

Here are my fragment activity classes,

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private ViewPager pager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final int page=2;

        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        pager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (pager.getCurrentItem()==page) {
                    return  true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            switch(pos) {

                case 0: return FirstFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment");
                case 1: return SecondFragment.newInstance("SecondFragment");
                case 2: return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment");
                case 3: return FourthFragment.newInstance("FourthFragment");
                case 4: return FifthFragment.newInstance("FifthFragment");
                default: return ThirdFragment.newInstance("DefaultFragment");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 5;
        }



    }

    public void setCurrentItem(int which) {
        if(pager != null && which >= 0 && which <= 4) {
            pager.setCurrentItem(which);
        }
    }
}
```

**SecondActivity.java**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class SecondActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private ViewPager pager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        final int page=2;

        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager_1);

        pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter2(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        pager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (pager.getCurrentItem()==page) {
                    return  true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    private class MyPagerAdapter2 extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyPagerAdapter2(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            switch(pos) {

                case 0: return FirstFragment_1.newInstance("FirstFragment_2");
                case 1: return SecondFragment_1.newInstance("SecondFragment_2");
                case 2: return ThirdFragment_1.newInstance("ThirdFragment_2");
                case 3: return FourthFragment_1.newInstance("FourthFragment_2");
                case 4: return FifthFragment_1.newInstance("FifthFragment_2");
                default: return ThirdFragment_1.newInstance("DefaultFragment_2");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 5;
        }



    }

    public void setCurrentItem(int which) {
        if(pager != null && which >= 0 && which <= 4) {
            pager.setCurrentItem(which);
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem** How could I do this?

Comment: Be more clear about what you want exactly.

Comment: what do you want exactly as for i m getting you have two fragments what do you want to do

Answer (score 0):

try overriding OnDetach() method in fifth fragment(fifthFragment.java) of the FirstActivity and inside ondetach() method call getActivity().startActivity(secondActivity);

Comment: Can you provide me more details with a sample ?